# How do I get AIX Tapeutil to list the contents of a tape I backed up?

Tags: aix, tape

I can't figure out how to get tapeutil to list the contents of a tape that I just backed up.

```
tapeutil -f /dev/rmt1 unmount
tapeutil -f /dev/rmt1 mount ${TODAY}
tapeutil -f /dev/rmt1 erase
tar -cvf /dev/rmt1 /backup
```

How do I list the files on the tape? Via tapeutil? ls?

Answer (score 2):

`tar` can list the contents of tape, rather than `tapeutil`. Locate tape at the beginning of data that you want to list and send the following command:

```
tar -tvf /dev/rmt1
```

Comment: that was 10 years and 4 jobs ago :) +1 from the grave